# "Hardware does not pass checks" issue in GNOME Settings

Tags: gnome-settings-daemon

It isn't affecting my user experience, but as settings says: "This means that you are not protected against common hardware security issues."
I've tried updating my firmware, but there's no updates though.

Here is the output:

```
Firmware Updater Verification:                   Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Swap:                                      Pass (Encrypted)
  Linux Kernel Lockdown:                           Pass (Enabled)
  Linux Kernel Verification:                       Pass (Not Tainted)
```

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with this output. I did a bit of my own research, and it was mostly on Fedora Linux, and people's outputs were far more detailed, but with this one it seems like everything is OK. Is this a graphical bug?

[image: a visual bug]